# Excel Macro Reciprocal Conversion between two columns (lbs/kg)

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first question here.
I am very new to excel macro/vba.
Can someone please guide me on how to create a macro which does the following:

when someone enters value into either column B (in kgs)/ or column C (in lbs), the other column gets automatically updated to reflect the appropriate value. For example, if someone entered the kgs value in column B then column c would show the lbs value and if someone entered the lbs value in column c then column b would would show the appropriate lbs value.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think this would be considered a circular reference so formulas may not work, but you can use VBA and `Worksheet_Change`

Comment: You could write a macro triggered by a change in either cell that will insert the value in the other cell. [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Worksheet.Change) could get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the VBE Editor and double-click on the sheet you want to monitor, you can place this Sub there:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim cel As Variant

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) = False Then Exit Sub

    If Target.Column = 2 Then

        ' data entered in column B, so change C
        Target.Offset(0,1).Value = Target.Value * 2.2

    ElseIf Target.Column = 3 Then

        ' data entered in column C, so change B
        Target.Offset(0,-1).Value = Target.Value / 2.2  

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I get a compile error  while trying to run. it highlights: Else If Target.Column = 3 Then

Comment: @xissa11 oops remove the space between Else and If

Comment: @xissa11 just please keep in mind this can break if you copy & paste a bunch of values

Comment: @xissa11 I added a line of code for it to exit if it detects a copy-paste